# How to make text appear in the text box but when it is clicked the text goes away, letting you type

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make text appear in the text box but dissapear when the text box is clicked.

I want it to be like this: https://gyazo.com/17087686454b0b884104dcf08c551de0

That is basically all I want.

**EDIT**: OP has indicated this is a `winforms` app

Comment: @JohnLord incorrect.  Also it's a bad assumption.  OP may want to just replicate the behavior in a different technology.  In this case he did - _WinForms_

Comment: @Terry Are you sure this is winforms and not the web? I am surprised given the answer you selected.

Comment: he didn't specify winforms originally and that's abnormal behavior for a winforms app.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use placeholder attribute should do it

Comment: What’s.a placeholder attribute?

Comment: Are you using HTML /web or a Windows application?

Comment: Placeholder attribute is on a test input element in HTML. If you want it to have text when the user opens the page you put the text you want in it. Just Google it. Also being new here it ticks me off someone would downvote my answer when it's not wrong!

Comment: _"Placeholder attribute is on a test input element in HTML"_ - prior to the OP's feedback, what made you think this was a HTML question?  Normally you shouldn't answer a question that isn't clearly defined. [ask].

Comment: OP has now indicated that it is a **WinForms** app so your answer doesn't apply

Comment: I had asked later for clarification, I don't have enough achievement to comment

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct method to add a placeholder to a text box. But you can do something like this easily.

```
Textbox newTextBox = new Textbox();
newTextBox.Text = "Search google or type URL";

newTextBox.GotFocus += GotFocus.EventHandle(RemoveText);
newTextBox.LostFocus += LostFocus.EventHandle(AddText);

public void RemoveText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (newTextBox.Text == "Search google or type URL") 
    {
     newTextBox.Text = "";
    }
}

public void AddText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newTextBox.Text))
        newTextBox.Text = "Search google or type URL";
}
```